# Could not upload multiple images into the database

Tags: android, kotlin

I am getting these errors when I am uploading images. The path is storing in database table, But the image folder does not have image.

**These are the errors**

E/ErrorUtil: Error: /document/primary:DCIM/Camera/20190804_111501.jpg (No such file or directory)
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /document/primary:DCIM/Camera/20190804_111501.jpg (No such file or directory)

Here I shared my code.

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK
            && null != data) {

        if(data.getClipData() != null) {
            val count = data.getClipData().getItemCount(); //evaluate the count before the for loop --- otherwise, the count is evaluated every loop.
            for(i in 0..count-1) {
                val imageUri : Uri = data.getClipData().getItemAt(i).uri
               // getRealPathFromURI(applicationContext,imageUri)

                imageUri.let {
                    Log.d("imageUri",it.toString())
                    Log.d("imagePath",it.path)
                    file = File(it.path)
                    val jj=Gson()
                    Log.d("fileIS",jj.toJson(file))
                    fileType = EnumUtils.FileType.IMAGE.value
                    val name = file!!.name
                    Log.d("fimenameis",name)
                    multipartArray!!.add(MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("files[]", file!!.name, RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(file!!.path.getMimeType()?: ""), file!!)))
                    val s = Gson()
                    Log.d("multipartArray",s.toJson(multipartArray).toString())
                }

            }

            //do something with the image (save it to some directory or whatever you need to do with it here)
    } else if(data.getData() != null) {
        val imagePath = data.getData().getPath();
            fileType = EnumUtils.FileType.IMAGE.value
            file = File(imagePath)
            multipartArray!!.add(MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("files[]", file!!.name, RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(file!!.path.getMimeType()?: ""), file!!)))
            Log.d("imagePath",imagePath.toString())
        //do something with the image (save it to some directory or whatever you need to do with it here)
    }

    }
```

Comment: is ```/document/primary:DCIM/Camera/20190804_111501.jpg``` the correct path?

Comment: Yes. it is the correct path.

Comment: That's contrary to what the error message says

Answer (score 0):

yes it happen some time due to file path does not get the absolute path and failed to convert it into file

```
      ` private fun getRealPathFromURI(contentURI: Uri): String? {
    val result: String?
    val cursor = contentResolver.query(contentURI, null, null, null, null)
    if (cursor == null) { // Source is Dropbox or other similar local file path
        result = contentURI.path
    } else {
        cursor.moveToFirst()
        val idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA)
        result = cursor.getString(idx)
        cursor.close()
    }
    return result
}`

 val file: File = File(getRealPathFromURI(Uri.parse(imagePath)))
```

Comment: i got the error ->  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.

Comment: try this or you can simple add your error in google and find many solution like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20240249/make-sure-the-cursor-is-initialized-correctly-before-accessing-data-from-it