# select * where id= {multiply values)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a list `List<Int32>` containing ids and want to select some values from another table where id=ids[0],ids[1],...

it look like this:

```
 string query=String.Format("@ SELECT values from Table WHERE id=???");
```

How to get result?

P.S. as i listen- that this way is not right.

So, another way to do that- use Join:

```
   string queryString = String.Format(@" SELECT * FROM Table1 [t1]
                                           join [Table2] [t2]  
                                           on [t1].idTable1=[t2].id where [idParamValue]={0}",  idParamValue);
```

So, then i should use :

```
using (var sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(queryString, _connection))
        {
            using (var sqlReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (sqlReader.Read())
                {
                    var param1=(String)sqlReader["param_name"];                 
                }
            }
        }
```

Thank you!

Comment: What version of sql are you running, the ways to solve this change if you are using Sql2008 or newer.

Comment: What you need is to "join" the other table. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: Are you using Entity framework in your apploication?

Comment: question is not clear enough.... according to your question the answer can be found in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803472/sql-where-id-in-id1-id2-idn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE id IN (79,86,42)
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use below query :-

```
string query=String.Format("@ SELECT values from Table WHERE id in(value1,value2,value3,value4,...)");
```