# asp.net is there a way to get id in list?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have a many-to-many between 'Edital' and 'Graduando' and I created a entity called 'EditalGraduando'. Now I want to know every 'edital' that 'graduando' subscribe using the graduando id. So I did this:

```
public IQueryable<int> GetGraduandosIds(int editalId)
{
    var graduandosId = db.EditalGraduandoe.Where(e => e.EditalId == editalId).Select(i => i.graduandoID);

    return graduandosId;
}
```

There's a way to do a select in the entety 'Graduando' using this result? Like this: [SQL WHERE ID IN (id1, id2, ..., idn)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5803472/4113979)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this:

```
public IQueryable<Graduandoe> GetGraduandos(IEnumerable<int> graduandosIds)
{
    return db.Graduandoe.Where(g => graduandosIds.Contains(g.graduandoID));
}
```

Alternatively, you could have navigation properties, and you can write the following instead of the two functions:

```
public IQueryable<Graduandoe> GetGraduandos(int editalId)
{
    return db.EditalGraduandoe.Where(e => e.EditalId == editalId).Select(i => i.Graduandoe);
}
```

Comment: Do you know where can I find the documentation to this?

Comment: How can I do join between entity Editals with the row Status from EditalGraduandoes (imgur.com/Ti4WUgR)?

 public IQueryable<Edital> GetEditalsIds(int graduandoId) { return db.EditalGraduandoe.Where(e => e.graduandoID == graduandoId).Select(i => i.Edital); //with a join here }

Comment: I found the documentation
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: And I found good examples, including join.
https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/understanding-linq-to-sql-4-data-retrieving-via-query-methods

Comment: and this is what I need it to get the Status too:
public IQueryable GetEditalsIds(int graduandoId)
        {
            return db.EditalGraduandoe.Where(e => e.graduandoID == graduandoId).Select(edital => new { Edital = edital.Edital, Status = edital.Status});
        }