# How to associate SQL data with outside data

Tags: sql, node.js

I've got a lot of new data coming into my program that I need to quickly associate with existing data in a table so I can then filter out the `approved: false` ones.

Here's as distilled as I can think to make the situation:

Given the following:

```
const list = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}]
// assume ~10K items, not necessarily 1-1 with the MyTable's rows.
```

```sql
INSERT INTO MyTable (id, approved) VALUES (1, TRUE), (2, FALSE), (3, TRUE);
-- assume ~10K rows
```

How to get to this?

```js
const result = [{id: 1, approved: true}, {id: 2, approved: false}] // only ids from list
```

I'm asking what SQL query will get from the givens to the result.

Comment: Your `result` looks like just a `SELECT * FROM MyTable`.  Did you have any logic behind your query?  Also, are you asking about SQL here or Node?

Comment: `result` should only contain ids that were in `list`, not all ids in `MyTable`. I'll edit the question to clarify that.

Comment: So why doesn't result also contain "3"? Where'd that guy go?

Comment: Or is this just something like `SELECT * FROM mytable where mytable.id in (your list)`? Like... you don't ACTUALLY want to insert here...?

Comment: I hear that `WHERE MyTable.id IN (1, 2, etc)` is very slow for thousands of ids.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a specific instance of [SQL WHERE ID IN (id1, id2, …, idn)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803472/sql-where-id-in-id1-id2-idn), so the answer is simply dump the ids IN the statement:

```js
const idsString = list.map(item => item.id).join() // sanitize!
const result = sql("SELECT id, approved FROM MyTable WHERE id IN (" + idsString + ");")
```