# Delete records from Amazon Redshift based on primary key column values stored in a file

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have 14k unique ids in a .txt file, based on which I want to delete data from Amazon RedShift table. I have tried keeping the records inside IN clause, but it is not working. The query keeps on running for a long time

Eg:

delete from <table_name> where <primary_key_column> in (1,2,3....,14000);

Answer (score 0):

Referring to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5803472/4434405) might help. It looks like using such a large 'in' statement is going to take the Db quite some time to process.

I would personally do something programmatically with a loop and break this down into multiple statements.

You could follow the programmatic approach another way and use a [transaction](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_BEGIN.html).

Something like:

```sql
begin read write;

delete from <table> where <col> = 1
...
delete from <table> where <col> = 14000

commit;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend:

- Load the text file as a new table
- Delete records where the ID is in that table

Something like:

```sql
DELETE FROM table1
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM table2)
```