# Bigquery for ID in a list

Tags: python, sql, google-bigquery, inner-join

Currently I know how to use the BigQuery Python API to make queries from `<company_warehouse>.<table>` in the form

```
SELECT id, field1, field2, ...
FROM '<company_warehouse>.<table>'
WHERE field1==...
```

What I'd like to do is perform the above query but add in a restriction to search only on a subset of the total data restricted to a large set (list) of IDs I have in Python (as a list or pandas Series). i.e., the same as adding a clause `WHERE id IN (id1,...,idn)`, but this method is inefficient for very large n.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803472/sql-where-id-in-id1-id2-idn) has some SQL answers suggesting to do it with inner joins, but the answers aren't written with clearly usable code (even in other SQL DBMS's). How do I get this done in BigQuery?

Answer (score 4):

You can write:

```
    WHERE field1 = ... AND 
        id IN UNNEST(['id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id4'])
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use an array:

```
SELECT id, field1, field2, ...
FROM '<company_warehouse>.<table>'
WHERE field1 = ... AND
      id in (select el from unnest(array[1, 2, 3]) el)
```

The `array[1, 2, 3]` can be passed in as a parameter.

Comment: How should I pass in the array as a parameter? Currently my query syntax takes a query as a string in Python